# Querying Active Directory with logged on user credentials in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm working on a C# application that requires a list of users to be spooled from Active Directory, an AD credential that has read-only privileges has been created but the organization has a policy for not giving a 3rd party user credentials.

Judging by [Nate's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866007/automatic-log-in-to-active-directory/) it is possible to query AD with the current logged on user. What I would like to know is do I have to preconfigure this in the AppPool Identity or will setting impersonate to "true" in my web.config as shown below solve this?

```
<identity impersonate="true" lockItem="false"/>
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/>
<authentication mode="Windows">
```

Below is the code I'm using to connect to AD to fetch my list of users:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(contextType, domainName))
{
   try
   {
       // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for all users
       UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
       qbeUser.Name = "*";

       // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
       PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher();
       srch.QueryFilter = qbeUser;

       // find all matches
       foreach (UserPrincipal result in srch.FindAll())
       {
           WindowsUser usr = new WindowsUser(result); // WindowsUser is my own user-defined class
           resultSet.Add(usr); // resultSet is a list of WindowsUser
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw ex;
   }
}

return resultSet;
```

Any answers will be greatly appreciated as I have to be at the clients office in a very short space of time.

Comment: You can define the credentials to use in another overload of the `PrincipalSearcher` constructor - see the MSDN docs for details!

Comment: I've gotten it to work without the credentials but I'm unable to specify the right wildcard for my query by example:
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
       qbeUser.Name = "*"; //what is the right wildcard to use here?